# how to layout the button item on ribbon pagegroup with the style like the picture

Tags: devexpress, ribbon

[image: this is the picture]
the large glyph all on the left . small glyph on the right with vertical allignment.
all the button are generated on the code.
this is my code using c# for winform showing
`RibbonPageGroup pagGroup = new RibbonPageGroup();
BarButtonItem barButtonItem = new BarButtonItem();
 pagGroup.ItemLinks.Add(barButtonItem);e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your [bar item links](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1087) into PageGroup one by one. For small items use the [BarItemLink.BeginGroup](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarItemLink_BeginGrouptopic) property to separate all the next items into [button group](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2516):

```
// ribbonPageGroup1
ribbonPageGroup.ItemLinks.Add(barButtonItem1);
ribbonPageGroup.ItemLinks.Add(barButtonItem2);
ribbonPageGroup.ItemLinks.Add(barButtonItem3, true); // begin group
ribbonPageGroup.ItemLinks.Add(barButtonItem4);
ribbonPageGroup.ItemLinks.Add(barButtonItem4);
```

Use the [BarItem.RibbonStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarItem_RibbonStyletopic) propety to specify [display options](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2517) for specific bar items:

```
barButtonItem3.RibbonStyle = DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonItemStyles.SmallWithText;
```